# Automatically import and update data from csv.gzip in csv

Tags: csv, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, export-to-csv

Working in a website that will host affiliate products. Every day the datasource file is updated. I've copied that data in another CSV to host on Woocommerce. Using WP Allimport and Easycsv I can automate any changes to that CSV to be reflected in Woocommerce accordingly.

The datasource file is a url with a csv.gzip download link. So right now I have to download it, unzip the csv file, and update the copied CSV for the changes to appear on Woocommerce.

Is there any way to automate that? Have the csv.gzip link be downloaded and unzipped to a csv every day for example?

I have little coding experience but hopefully someone has a solution.

Much appreciated,

Kris

Tried the =importdata from a url function on Google Sheets, but since it's a csv.gzip file it has to be unzipped first. Can't show the data from a csv.gzip directly in Google Sheets (to my knowledge)

Comment: I think that if your `a csv.gzip download link` is the direct link of the ZIP data including the CSV data and the link can be accessed from Google side, your goal can be achieved by a custom function created by Google Apps Script. For example, how about the following flow?

Comment: 1. Download the ZIP data from the URL using [UrlFetchApp.fetch()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/url-fetch/url-fetch-app#fetch(String)). 2. Unzip the downloaded ZIP data using [Utilities.unzip()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/utilities/utilities#unzipblob). 3. Parse the unzipped csv data using [Utilities.parseCsv()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/utilities/utilities#parsecsvcsv).

Comment: You probably need to load the file into your GDrive first. Afterwards, see [this page](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/samples/automations/import-csv-sheets)